# R, ggplot2, limit rows in a faceted barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Sup,

Consider the following lines:

## data

```
df=data.frame(
      prod=sample(1:30, 1000, replace=TRUE),
      mat=sample(c('yes', 'no'), 1000, replace=TRUE),
      fj=sample(c(1,2), 1000, replace = TRUE)
      )
```

## plot

```
df %>%
  group_by(mat, prod, fj) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(prod, n), y = n)) +
  geom_col(fill = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[2], colour = "grey", alpha = 0.8) +
  labs(x = "Prod", y = "Qnt") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(fj ~ mat, scale="free") +
  theme_minimal()
```

which gives me
[image: plot]

Now, if i drop `fj` variable, as in

```
df %>%
  group_by(mat, prod) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(prod, n), y = n)) +
  geom_col(fill = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[2], colour = "grey", alpha = 0.8) +
  labs(x = "Prod", y = "Qnt") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ mat, scale="free") +
  theme_minimal()
```

`slice(1:5)` does it's job and i've got:

[image: plot2]

## Question

why `slice` and `reorder` doesn't seems to work properly when there's 3+ variables and what should i do to limit the first plot to 5 lines each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `summarize` you loose one level of grouping.  In this case, you lost fj, so when you `slice` it's not included in the group divisions.

If you first `ungroup` then `group_by` mat and fj, I think you'll end up with what you are looking for.

```
df %>%
      group_by(mat, prod, fj) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()) %>% 
      ungroup()%>%
      group_by(mat,  fj) %>% 
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      slice(1:5) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(prod, n), y = n)) +
      geom_col(fill = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[2], colour = "grey", alpha = 0.8) +
      labs(x = "Prod", y = "Qnt") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
      coord_flip() +
      facet_wrap(fj ~ mat, scale="free") +
      theme_minimal()
```

[image]

This leaves the problem of reordering the prod variable within each facet.  It doesn't work in the example above because you are ordering by the entire data frame, and some of the values of Prod are repeated in several of the facets.  As discussed in this [blog post](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets) by @drsimonj  you need to create an order variable and plot based on that.  This follows/blatently copies the method outlined in the blog post.

```
df %>%
      group_by(mat, prod, fj) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()) %>% 
      group_by(mat,  fj) %>% 
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      slice(1:5) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(fj,mat, n) %>%  # arrange the entire table by the facets first, then by the n value
      mutate(row.order = row_number()) %>%  # create dummy variable
      ggplot(aes(x = row.order, y = n)) +  # plot by the dummy variable
      geom_col(fill = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[2], colour = "grey", alpha = 0.8, position = "dodge") +
      labs(x = "Prod", y = "Qnt") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
      scale_x_continuous(   # add back in the Prod values 
            breaks = df2$row.order,
            labels = df2$prod
      )+
      coord_flip() +
      facet_wrap(fj ~ mat, scales = "free") +
      theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Why does it happens tho (lose grouping level)? It's always the last variable set in `group_by()` that is lost? How do i know which variables set to `group_by()` after `ungroup()`?

Comment: You always lose the last variable set in the `group_by`.  I don't have a great answer as to why, but the documentation for summarize reads that it returns "An object of the same class as .data. One grouping level will be dropped."  In your case, you want to group by the variables you are going use for your faceting.  FWIW it looks like it works the same if you don't ungroup first.

Comment: This doesn't answer your other question, but this blog post looks like it could help: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets